# After game exit WP7, tiles/list menu jerk on touh swipe

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

my xna + wp7 game has 30 - 35 content instances and it loads at once in game life time. when this game exists(by pressing back button) Windows phone 7 tiles/list menu jerks on touch swipe.  is it because my game is missing some releasing contents/resources ?

Comment: or it might be because of releasing all the resources at once?

Comment: you could run separate threads to destroy the resources and see if it makes any difference? And if you are running in Emulator , the frame rate would be low. So I suggest , try running it in device and see if you get the same result.